# Send key doesn't trigger key up or key down

Tags: javascript, casperjs

Im sending keys to a input filter using sendkeys and supposed to be it will update the contents of the table, I check its screenshot and it placed the characters on the field. unfortunately after sendkeys, it doesnt trigger either keyup/keydown.

How to trigger keyup or keydown on casper?

Code:

```
this.sendKeys('input[name=\"filterString\"]', 'string');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`casper.sendKeys()` should have triggered the keyup and keydown events, because it uses native browser events which should be indistinguishable from user input in other browsers.

You trigger it yourself by keeping focus and then triggering those events:

```
this.sendKeys('input[name=\"filterString\"]', 'string', {keepFocus: true});
this.page.sendEvent("keydown");
this.page.sendEvent("keyup");
this.page.sendEvent("keypress");
```

For this you can use the underlying PhantomJS function [`page.sendEvent()`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/send-event.html).

Comment: I tried the code, unfortunately it didn't work for me.

Comment: What PhantomJS version do you have? Please register to the `resource.error`, `page.error`, `remote.message` and `casper.page.onResourceTimeout` events ([Example](https://gist.github.com/artjomb/4cf43d16ce50d8674fdf)). Maybe there are errors.

Comment: using phantomjs 1.9.2 and casperjs 1.1.0, it doesnt seem to have any errors. usually it stops the script when it has errors right? im very new with casperjs

Comment: v1.9.2 is really old. Try upgrading to at least 1.9.7. If you install CasperJS from git, then you can also use PhantomJS 2.0.0

Comment: same thing on 1.9.7 without errors, doesnt trigger the keyup nor keydown, but I can still see that it sent the text on the textbox, it just didnt trigger any function that would update table contents.

Comment: Do i need to specifiy which filed I need to sendEvent keyup/keydown?

Comment: Yes, sorry, I have forgotten it.